# Java/MySQL/Console Application: Insert Row into method from switch-case statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, console-application, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I have a couple questions about my code. I am trying to implement the ability for the user to insert rows into the insertInfo() method below. I am only focused on the accounts table so if you decide to test it in the console just input 1 for each menu option.

1. I have not been able to achieve this without throw exceptions/try catch statements, is it possible to without them?
2. I'm getting an error `NullPointerException` when I try to add an account.

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Menu
{
    static boolean exit;
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/chocolatemilk_review";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";
    static final String QUERY = "SELECT account_id, last, first, address, city, state, email FROM Accounts";
    static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO Accounts ";
    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static void main (String [] args) throws SQLException {
        mainMenuOptions();
    }

    public Connection connect() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    }

    public static void mainMenuOptions() throws SQLException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //do while didnt work here? had to put after variable line 32/33

        out.println("Choconnoisseur Menu");
        out.println();
        out.println("Enter 1 for Accounts ");
        out.println("Enter 2 for Merchandise ");
        out.println("Enter 3 for Merchsales ");
        out.println("Enter 4 for Product Reviews ");
        out.println("Enter 5 to Exit"); 
        out.println();
        out.println("Enter number here: ");
        int numEntered = input.nextInt(); 
        input.nextLine();

        do {
            switch(numEntered) {
            case 1: 
                accountsTable();
                out.println("Account Options");
                break;
            case 2: 
                merchandiseTable();
                out.println("Merchandise Options");
                break;
            case 3: 
                merchsalesTable();
                out.println("Merchsales Options");
                break;
            case 4: 
                producReviewsTable();
                out.println("Product Reviews Options");
                break;
            case 5: 
                exit = true;
                out.println("Have a nice day! "); 
                out.println();
                break;
            }

            out.println("Choconnoisseur Menu");
            out.println();
            out.println("Enter 1 for Accounts ");
            out.println("Enter 2 for Merchandise ");
            out.println("Enter 3 for Merchsales ");
            out.println("Enter 4 for Product Reviews ");
            out.println("Enter 5 to Exit"); 
            out.println();
            out.println("Enter number here: ");
        }
        while (numEntered != 5);  
    }

    public static void accountsTable() throws SQLException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //do while didn't work here? had to put after variable line 32/33

        out.println("Accounts Table");
        out.println();
        out.println("Enter 1 for Add Account");
        out.println("Enter 2 for Edit Account");
        out.println("Enter 3 for  Remove Account");
        out.println("Enter 4 for View Account");
        out.println("Enter 5 back to Main Menu"); 
        out.println();
        out.println("Enter number here: ");
        int accountOpts = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        do {
            switch (accountOpts) {
            case 1: 
                insertInfo();
                out.println("Add Accounts");
                break;
            case 2: 
                deleteAccounts();
                out.println("Edit Accounts");
                break;
            case 3: 
                deleteAccounts(); 
                out.println("Remove Accounts");
                break;
            case 4: 
                selectAccounts();
                out.println("View Accounts");
                break;
            case 5: 
                out.println("Back to Main Menu ");
                out.println();
                break;
            }

            out.println("Accounts Table");
            out.println();
            out.println("Enter 1 for Add Account");
            out.println("Enter 2 for Edit Account");
            out.println("Enter 3 for  Remove Account");
            out.println("Enter 4 for View Account");
            out.println("Enter 5 back to Main Menu"); 
            out.println();
            out.println("Enter number here: ");

        }
        while(accountOpts != 5);
    }

    private static void insertInfo() throws SQLException 
    {
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts(account_id, last, first, address, city, state, email)" +
                ("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "Val 1");
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "Val 2");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "Val 3");
        preparedStatement.setString(4, "Val 4");
        preparedStatement.setString(5, "Val 5");
        preparedStatement.setString(6, "Val 6");
        preparedStatement.setString(7, "Val 7");
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }

    private static void deleteAccounts()
    {
    }

    private static void selectAccounts()
    {
    }

    private static void merchandiseTable()
    {
    }

    private static void merchsalesTable()
    {
    }

    private static void producReviewsTable()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?` You missed `);`

Comment: Thanks  However I'm still getting the error 

Answer (score 1):

The connection variable is null and this could be why you get a NullPointerException. You have defined the connect() method which opens the connection to the database, but I don't see where it was called. When using connection in insertInfo() you should first call connect() assigning the return value to connection.

```
connection = connect();
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
```

Also the sql query is malformed and you should write it like this:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts(account_id, last, first, address, city, state, email)" + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

or like this:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts(account_id, last, first, address, city, state, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```